# Finding strobogrammatic number in range of 1000000

Tags: python

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to find all the strobogrammatic numbers in range of 1000000. Could something like this work? It does have a few mistakes.

```
a=[]
for d in range(1,1000000):
    d=str(d)
    for i in str(d):
        if i == '0' or i  == '1' or i  == '8' or i  == '6' or i  == '9':
            if not '2' or '4' or '5' or '7' in d:
                a.append([int(d)])
print(a)
```

It gives me 2,4,6,7 even if I didn't include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
if not '2' or '4' or '5' or '7' in d:
```

That's not a valid way to check whether any of those is in the string - you end up checking whether `'2'` is falsey (it's not), and then whether `'4'`, `'5'` are truthy (they are), and finally, whether `'7' in d` (which may be true or false).  Something like this would work though:

```
if not any(num in d for num in "2457"):
```